# XMLStreamException :Trying to output second root, StaXparser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

```
writer.writeStartElement(startElement.getName().getLocalPart());
```

//when i run on standalone machine with one thread, it works fine, but when i run the multiple jobs with  multiple threads on the server it gives me the following error at

```
writer.writeStartElement(startElement.getName().getLocalPart());

javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to output second root, <element>

ERROR [STDERR] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
 Trying to output second root, <handset>
ERROR [STDERR] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4)  at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1473)
ERROR [STDERR] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4)  at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1480)
ERROR [STDERR] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4)  at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1508)
ERROR [STDERR] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4)  at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.checkStartElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:444)
ERROR [STDERR] (JBossQuartzScheduler_Worker-4)  at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeStartElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:292)
```

Comment: Are you using the _same_ XMLStreamWriter in more than one thread with no synchronization?  That's pretty much guaranteed to fail, or at least mangle the XML.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yeah, but iam executing as different jobs

Comment: i have posted my code